# Vala with yaml recursing the document

Tags: yaml

Here's a basic Vala file that reads a Yaml into FileStream and produces Document and Stream events, and lately Scalar value or other events. I'm interested in obtaining the actual values or scalars or tag names instead of just Event,
Figuring out where is the Yaml FileStream loaded document content available to parse, or how to map events out from the parse scanner directly into Glib.GNode n-ary-trees.

```
// compile with:  valac --vapidir ./VAPI/vala-extra-vapis/ --pkg yaml-0.1 --pkg gio-2.0 --pkg glib-1.0 yaml.vala

public static int main(string[] args) {
    bool done = false;
    Yaml.Parser parser = Yaml.Parser();                 /* Create the Parser object. */
    Yaml.Event event = Yaml.Event();    
    Yaml.Token token = Yaml.Token();
    
    // Yaml.TagDirective tag = Yaml.Tag.;
    // Yaml.Document doc = Yaml.Document(null, tag, tag, 0, 0);
    // string input = "..."; /* Set a string input. */
    // size_t length = input.length;

    FileStream file = FileStream.open("systemd-calls.yaml", "r");
    assert(file!=null);

    parser.set_input_file(file);
    
    Yaml.Encoding encoding = Yaml.Encoding.UTF8;
    event.stream_start_initialize(encoding);

    while (!done) {        
        // if (!parser.parse(out event)) { error(); }
        parser.parse(out event);                        /* Get the next event. */
        parser.scan(out token);

        bool c = (bool)(event.type == Yaml.EventType.STREAM_START);
        bool a = (bool)(event.type == Yaml.EventType.DOCUMENT_START);

        bool b = (bool)(event.type == Yaml.EventType.DOCUMENT_END);        
        done = (bool)(event.type == Yaml.EventType.STREAM_END);
        print(@"$(a) $(b) $(c) $(done) \n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void error(){}
```

I started using Valac compiler recently with great success recently. compiled several apps and coded another few. Now i wanted to integrate Yaml support in some code but i find the respective VAPI for yaml `yaml-0.1.vapi` file to have no explain on uses, so i managed to write a basic utility to understand the VAPI intrinsic calls to the header files straight copying a C file and figuring out the calls; very quick for extending APIs. [code below].
My problem currently is where is the loaded document content available to parse, or how to map events out from the parse scanner directly into Glib.GNode n-ary-trees. The second problem i see is i couldn't figure out to build the vala-language-server which is essential for figuring out classes autonomously without reading all the VAPI a hundred times. Currently vala-language-server maps to vala-0.48* while the Linux distro available vala is 0.46. Can you hand me some clue or version availability of the language-server to build against 0.46?